# Differences between iPhone and iPod Touch

Tags: ios, iphone, web-applications, ipod-touch

I am looking for the cheapest way to test websites and HTML email on a device that behaves like "the latest iPhone running the latest iOS". I have heard that the iPod Touch 6 is supposedly identical to the iPhone 6, except for not having a GSM radio chip.

From a developer perspective, what are the differences between the iPhone and the iPod Touch? Do they run the exact same OS? And if I eventually move on to proper iOS apps, will these behave exactly the same on an iPod Touch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iPod touch runs iOS exactly like an iPhone... same updates and same apps, the only thing is that you can't use the hardware that the iPod doesn't have (GSM).